# Reference to type 'httpsessionstatebase' claims it is defined in 'system.web', but it could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've been having this problem for days now, and i don't find a way to fix this. I want to validate a login check on ASP.NET MVC, and im using the variable session for it. The thing is Session always marks an error and stating the following [Image containing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puTEI.png)

This is my controller code:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using PresupuestosPruebas.Models;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace PresupuestosPruebas.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(Usuario objUser)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (ASHPF_PRESUPUESTOSContext db = new ASHPF_PRESUPUESTOSContext())
                {
                    var obj = db.Usuarios.Where(a => a.NombreUsuario.Equals(objUser.NombreUsuario) && a.ContraseñaUsuario.Equals(objUser.ContraseñaUsuario)).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (obj != null)
                    {

                        Session["IdUsuario"] = obj.IdUsuario.ToString();
                        Session["NombreUsuario"] = obj.NombreUsuario.ToString();
                        return RedirectToAction("UserDashboard");
                    }
                }
            }
            return View(objUser);
        }

        public ActionResult UserDashBoard()
        {
            if (Session["IdUsuario"] != null)
            {
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my startup also

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using PresupuestosPruebas.Models;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace PresupuestosPruebas
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //Configuracion de cadena de conexion
            services.AddDbContext<ASHPF_PRESUPUESTOSContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddSession();
            services.AddMvc();
            
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseSession();

            
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have System.Web.dll in your reference list? Namespaces may spread over different assemblies, e.g. System.dll contains parts of System.Web namespace too. If you do not add the assembly which really contains the type you try to use the IDE wont find it.

Comment: Where can i find my reference list? And in case I don't have System.Web.dll  on my reference list, how do I add it to the list?

Comment: Look for "Add Reference..." in right-click menu in Solution Explorer.

Comment: There are 4 options Project References, Shared Project References, COM References, and Service Reference, none of them had the System.Web.Dll nor i could find a way to include it as reference. It is via NuGet package that I download the dll?